# tar to tape and file with encryption

Tags: openssl, tar, redirection

I am trying to encrypt our tape backups, using tar and openssl but also write to a local file, so far I have :

```
tar --total -czp ./tmp ./home | tee /tmp/Archive.tar.gz | tee > /dev/nst0
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct `tee` sytax but it works, because

```
tar -tzvf /dev/nst0
```

and

```
tar -tzvf /tmp/Archive.tar.gz
```

give the correct results.

However if I try to add encryption using openssl :

```
tar --total -czp ./tmp ./home | openssl aes-256-cbc -e -salt -pass file:/encrp_file  | tee /tmp/Archive.tar.gz | tee > /dev/nst0
```

I get :

```
tee: standard output: Invalid argument
tee: write error
```

I assume that there is something in the output from `openssl` that is causing a problem for `tee` when it writes to the tape because the *file* is created properly and if I remove the output to `tee` and just send it to the tape it also works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that last `tee` necessary ? Maybe you can replace it with `|tee /tmp/Archive.tar.gz >/dev/nst0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the relevant line from my home backup script:

```
tar czfTP - $FILELIST --use-compress-program xz | openssl bf -salt -pass file:passkey.txt | tee /backup/location/file_name.txz.bfe | dd bs=10k of=/dev/tape
```

You can just create the backup files and copy them to tape later with

```
dd if=/backup/file.tar of=/dev/tap bs=10k
```

And there are plenty of other possible combinations. I'm using Blowfish Encryption, looks like you're wanting AES, but that's easy to swap out. I know others commonly use GPG instead of OpenSSL. It's also possible to setup asymmetric keys (AES or DSS) to generate a unique session key and prepend that to the file stream, but this is quite a bit more complicated, and makes parsing the encrypted file more complicated as well. But it's very useful for environments where the backup will be shipped off site and you don't want people onsite to be able to tamper with the backups.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked on decryption:

```
$ tar --total -czp /home |openssl aes-256-cbc -e -salt -pass file:pass.txt | tee /tmp/archive.tgz.encrypted > /tmp/archive2.tgz.encrypted
```

I don't have a tape device, so I'm sending it to two different files.  Should work with a tape drive, though.

So, the decryption looks like:

```
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -pass file:pass.txt -in /tmp/archive.tgz |tar --total -xzvf -
```

and I get no errors.

b0fh's comment to your post is correct.  The proper "tee" syntax is along the lines of

```
$ command | tee outputfile1 > outputfile2
```

Comment: Thanks for the `tee` syntax suggestion, the command works when outputting to two files as above but if I replace the `> /tmp/archive2.tgz.encrypted` with `> /dev/nst0` I get the same error.

Comment: What if you put the tape devices first, as the argument of the tee?  tee /dev/nst0 > /tmp/Archive.tar.gz

Comment: Most tape devices require 10k blocks, you'll have to pipe to a `dd of=/dev/tape bs=10k` to marshal the block size.